# Jenkins: no email to recipients (integration with GitLab)

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I'm using Jenkins  (with Email Extension plugin ... ), integrated with GitLab.

For my job in my post build actions configuration, I see this (note that the recipients list is empty ...)

[image]

When the job fails I see this in the console output

```
15:29:50 New run name is '#25'
15:29:51 Sending e-mails to: name1.surname1@mydomain.com name2.surname2@mydomain.com 
name3.surname3@mydomain.com
```

and emails are sent.

Where are these names found/are coming?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your E-mail Notification is configured with the *Send separate e-mails to individuals who broke the build* option enabled. This makes the Mailer Plugin send a notification to each e-mail address [involved in committing Changes](https://github.com/jenkinsci/mailer-plugin#usage) for the build in case the build failed.

Changes and their authors are shown at each job page.

For example, there are 4 Git commits from 4 different authors (identified by email). Those commits gets pushed to the Git server and Jenkins job gets started. The job picks all those new commits and fails. The plugin then picks all distinct emails from the commits and sends an email to each commit author assuming at least one of them broke the build.

Comment: Thanks Yuri for the quick reply. This is quite clear, but I dont't know where the committers name and email are scored and where jenkins get them  ... the recipient list in the job configuration is empty and I don't know how it work and I'd like to understand

Comment: ..   stored not "scored" ... sorry

Comment: Your Jenkins job likely begins with obtaining the code form a configured Version Control System (VCS) - Git, SVN, etc. In your case the VCS is GitLab. Each user of the VCS is identified by email. So each change stored in the VCS contains the author's email. Jenkins simply extracts the emails from the relevant changes.

Comment: So, this information is not "stored" in jenkins but obtained dynamically at each job execution that "download" or "access" to the code stored on the VCS (Git***, SVN,ecc ...). And this is indipendent from the field recipient content. Right?

Comment: Contacts given via the Recipients field get added to the ones obtained from the VCS changes.